# Change list into normal string [Python3]

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have a list full of strings, like `List = ["A","B","C"]`
And i wonder if i can somehow change that list into something used for an if statement. for example: `if ("A" "B" "C") in "ABCDEFGHIJ": ...`

If that is possible, i'd like to know.
Thank you!

Comment: not sure what you are asking... `''.join(["A","B","C"]) = 'ABC'`; that would work in your `if` statement.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if *each* string is in the target, if *any* string is in the target, or if the concatenation of all the strings is in the target?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a list of Boolean values where index i tells you if the ith element is in the string. For example

```
>>> x = ["A", "B", "C", "Z"]
>>> [i in "ABCDEFG" for i in x]
[True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: @JessaTehCrw: If the answer solves your problem, it's appropriate to upvote it (click the arrow above the score to the left of the answer); if it solves it better than any other answer, it's appropriate to click the checkbox, both to reward the answerer, and to indicate the question has been fully answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if every item is in the string:

```
if all(letter in "ABCDEFGHIJ" for letter in ["A", "B", "C"]):
```

If you want to check if any item is in the string:

```
if any(letter in "ABCDEFGHIJ" for letter in ["A", "B", "C"]):
```

Comment: You should drop the outer brackets here; `any` and `all` can short-circuit (`any` when it sees a single truthy value, `all` when it sees a falsy value), so pre-generating all the values wastes a lot of effort if the first value leads to a short-circuit. It also means using `O(n)` memory for the temporary `list` created by the list comprehension, rather than `O(1)` memory for the equivalent generator expression.